# How to create inline URL button in telegram via telegram bot using PHP?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to send a message with url button to my telegram channel using telegram bot.
I have string

```
msg = "Hello, Welcome To My Telegram Channel"
imageURL = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/08/11/14/34/greeting-5480092_1280.png"

buttonUrl = "FaceBook - https://facebook.com | YouTube - https://youtube.com | Twitter - https://twitter.com
Instagram - https://instagram.com"
```

I want to create a post like this :

[image]

Please help me or suggest any guide line.. Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need it anymore, because a year is passed, but I answer for who will see that, firstly you need to set up the possibility to put a button in a message, in this way:

```
function sendMessage($id, $text, $button = null){
    GLOBAL $token;
    switch(isset($button)){
        case true:
            $H = '&reply_markup={"inline_keyboard":['.$button.']}';
            $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=$id&parse_mode=HTML&text=".urlencode($text).$H;
            break;
        default:
            $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$token."/sendMessage?chat_id=$id&parse_mode=HTML&text=".urlencode($text);
            break;
    }
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Obviously use the variables' names you gave them, maybe you didn't call the token variable $token and so on.

Then you can put the button variable there, to define a button with a link do this:

```
$button = '[{"text":"'.urlencode("Link").'","url":"https://www.m1001.eu"}]';
```

If you want to define more than one button in the same row do this:

```
$button = '[{FIRST BUTTON},{SECOND BUTTON},{THIRD BUTTON}]';
```

To put them in different rows do this:

```
$button = '[{FIRST BUTTON}],[{SECOND BUTTON}],[{THIRD BUTTON}]';
```

You can also make a mix:

```
$button = '[{FIRST BUTTON},{SECOND BUTTON}],[{THIRD BUTTON}]';
```

Then just put the button that you defined when you use the sendMessage function:

```
sendMessage($id, 'Check this out!', $button);
```

You can also use button with callback data to make the bot edit messages or doing something else when the user clicks the button, but this is another long speech